# .net core console app calling PHP rest API with basic authentication

Tags: c#, php, rest, api, console-application

I am not able to get the data from a php rest api from the .net core console app(the call works fine from POSTMAN). I use below code for basic authentication and looks like it redirects to **https://www.thesite.org/login** for HttpClient.

Not sure what I am missing.

```
static async Task<RootObject> GetOrderDataAsync()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        RootObject result = null;
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.thesite.org/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("orders/processing");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RootObject>();

        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Would you mind pasting your postman curl?  (you can easily export to curl in postman)

Comment: C#

var client = new RestClient("https://www.thesite.org/orders/processing");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("postman-token", "67edddfdff87-e89bd51ae6a3");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic  ???????????????");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

Comment: curl
curl -X GET \
  https://www.thesite.org/orders/processing \
  -H 'authorization: Basic ????????????' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'postman-token: adfdfsdf567ddfdddf3941'

Answer (score 0):

I think when you use `AuthenticationHeaderValue` you don't need to explicitly convert to a Base64 string.  Have you tried:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "username:password");
```